# How to determine the mapping is onto?

Tags: functions

let f:N maps to I

Y=x-1000

Is it onto?

The far I got is that:

$Y=x-1000$
so, $X=1000+y$

Say we choose $y=2\in I$, then $\exists x=1002\in N$(as definition says)
So $f$ is onto.
But the book shows $1002\in I$. Why it is show while the definition itself says...$\forall y\in Y\exists x\in X$ s.t. $f(x)=y$.

Comment: If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s correct that the function is invertible thus is onto. As an alternative, it’s sufficient to note that $f$ is a continuos function and limits to $x\to \pm \infty$ are $\pm \infty$.

Comment: So if I write 1002€N instead of 1002€I. Is there a problem.